# Confused about the for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, iteration

The result of this function is: "yoyo my brother".

Why is yo added only on the first iteration, why the result isn't: "yoyo yomy yobrother"?

```
function myFunction() {
  var cars = ["yo", "my", "brother"];
  var i = 2;
  var len = cars.length;
  var text = "yo";

  for (; i < len; i++) { //typo, var i=0;
    text += cars[i]+ " ";
 }
};
```

Oh sry, I don't know how I missed that typo xD. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are there typos in the code you shared? You declare `i` outside of the for loop

Comment: Why do you think it would be `"yoyo yomy yobrother"`? Also you probably want to define `i` as: `var i = 0;`.

Comment: @Harangue I don't think that's a typo.

Comment: I think it is a typo, the loop would run once with his code and the value of text would be "yo brother ".

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

- You should set your `i` to `0` to start at the first
     value of the array.
- You set
     another variable for the `yo` text to be constant for appending and make the `text` variable blank.

If you want to get the "yoyo yomy yobrother" result do something like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var cars = ["yo", "my", "brother"];

  var len = cars.length;
  var text = "";
  var yotext = "yo";

  for (i=0; i < len; i++) {
    text += yotext +cars[i]+ " ";
 }
 console.log(text);
};

myFunction();
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pvk7yfew/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes you meant to initialize i to 0.

Because the `+=` operator appends text to the existing string. You're doing the following:

First iteration: `"yo" + "yo" + " " = "yoyo "`

Second iteration: `"yoyo " + "my" + " " = "yoyo my "`

Third iteration: `"yoyo my " + "brother" + " " = "yoyo my brother "`

Answer (score 0):

You typically have three parts to a for loop:

1) An initializer - gives the variable a starting point
2) A condition - will only run the loop if it is true
3) A modifier - changes the value of the variable

Therefore a typical for loop will look like this:

```
for (var i = 2; i < len; i++){

}
```

The loop will execute in this fashion:

1. Initialize i to the value of 2.
2. Check to see if the condition is true (2 is less than 3)
3. It Enters the loop and adds cars[2] to text. In other words it adds  'brother' to text.
4. This iteration of the loop is done. The i++ now adds 1 to i. i is now 3.
5. The condition is checked. i is no longer less than len (3 is not less than 3). So the program exits from the loop.

Is there a reason you are starting the value of i at 2 and not 0?

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down the code.

We have an array, cars, that contains 3 items. You then declare `i`, which later serves as your iterator (a counter) in the for loop. I'm going to go ahead and assume that was unintentional and you meant for the `i` to be inside the for loop

```
for (var i=0; i<len; i++)
```

A for loop repeats the code inside of its brackets a specified number of times. The first part of the for statement, behind the first semicolon, is the iterator. `i` will change on each run of the loop based on the 3rd section of the statement, in this case `i++`. This means increasing `i` by 1. The second section of the for statement states that the loop will only repeat while `i` is less than `len` - in this case, the number of items in our array, 3.

Finally, inside the for loop there is the line `text += cars[i] + "";` That's telling JavaScript to put strings together each time the for loop runs. We start with `"yo"` and then on each run:

```
i    string
-------------------------
0    "yoyo "
1    "yoyo my"
2    "yoyo my brother"
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the code does not prepend "yo" (initial value of `text`) to `cars[i]+ " "`, instead it prepends `text` the value of which is changing with the loop.

I believe you are rather confused with the `+=` operator than with the loop.

The line `text += cars[i]+ " ";` is equivalent to `text = text + cars[i]+ " ";`.

Going through your loop the value of `text` will change with each iteration, like below.

```
- yo
0 yoyo
1 yoyo my
2 yoyo my brother
```

Thus, the value of `text` will change in the first loop iteration, and it will no longer be "yo". So, no wonder "yoyo yomy yobrother" does not work out.